# How do you do this *without* using a calculator? The ratio of three numbers is $3\frac{1}{3}:4\frac{1}{5}:6\frac{1}{8}$

Tags: ratio

The ratio between three numbers is:

Three and one third: Four and one fifth: Six and one eighth and the sum of the numbers is $4197$. What are the three numbers?

Using a calculator, I would just add up the numbers which equals $13\frac{79}{120}$, divide $4197$ by $13\frac{79}{120}$ and then multiply each of the numbers in the ratio by that answer.

Without a calculator, the arithmetic seems impossible, or is there an easier way?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math formatting. And I don't see, why the arithmetic is impossible without calculator.:)

Comment: Oh wow, that looks way too hard for me

Comment: You want the ratio to be simplified ?

Comment: The arithmetic would be 1. Add the fractions. 2. Divide 4197 by that answer.  3. Multiply each fraction in the ratio by that answer.

Comment: How does the arithmetic seem impossible?

Answer (score 2):

The simplified ratio is as follows:
$$\frac{10}{3}:\frac{21}{5}:\frac{49}{8}$$
$$400:504:735$$

You can find the actual numbers by using the above ratio and the sum of the numbers.

$$400x+504x+735x = 4197$$
$$x = \frac{4197}{1639}$$

Comment: 21/5 is correct.

Comment: I got the simplified ratios by converting the mixed numbers to improper fractions, but then what do I do?

Comment: @little Multiply each of the fractions with 120

Comment: Oh that makes so much more sense now... Since the LCM is 120 for all of them, I can multiply all the ratios by 120. Thanks :)

Comment: @LittleBlackDog were you able to proceed from where I left and get the result ?